# I've added a module in redmine, how can I enable it for many projects at once?

Tags: redmine

I've got all these great new plugins enabled, and I can enable them on any given project.

However, I don't see a way to add/remove them from many projects at once.

Perhaps I need a module management plugin? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In my case Redmine 3.1.0 and MySQL is used as DB server. I think, you'll get the main idea in case of other confuguration.

```
DELETE FROM `enabled_modules` WHERE `name` = 'module_name_here';
INSERT INTO `enabled_modules` 
    (`project_id`, `name`) 
SELECT 
    `id`, 'module_name_here' 
FROM 
    `projects`
```

You can activate module for one project to discover its name from enabled_modules. Or you can find it in plugin sources, it should look like *'project_module :module_name_here'*

**Please, don't do this if you do not completely understand, what is this answer about!**

PS: Yes, I know - it is a dirty solution, but it's fast and easy enough for operation which is neccesary once a year or less.

Comment: This worked perfectly. You might want to add 'where status = 1' on the projects SELECT statement, as to only create the association to ACTIVE projects

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while and I reckon the OP has since solved his problem. In case someone else has the same problem:

We also had to activate a few modules in all projects and wrote a small script to do it for us:
https://github.com/EugenMayer/enable_chiliproject_modules

**Edit:**
This was created and tested for the Redmine fork "Chiliproject" but should work without changes in Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I enable it many projects at once?

You can't - at least not by using the UI.

Comment: Well, I feel better knowing I wasn't missing something.... now to see about that plugin

Comment: Oh, I thought that was a rhetorical question. Do you need one? I guess it depends on how many existing projects you have and how often you install/remove plugins. Plugins can be found at http://www.redmine.org/plugins. Otherwise, you may get lucky automating the activation of plugins by using the rails console runner (example for project creation http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/7406)